# Error log after updating magento 1.8 to 1.9

Tags: error, upgrade

After updating magento 1.8 to 1.9 im getting this error log and i don't know what to do about it. Can anybody tell me ?

```
    Invalid method Mage_Tax_Block_Adminhtml_Notifications::isDefaultStoreWithConflictingFptTaxConfigurationSettings(Array
(
)
)

Trace:
#0 /home/tuinshop/public_html/app/design/adminhtml/default/default/template/tax/notifications.phtml(58): Varien_Object->__call('isDefaultStoreW...', Array)
#1 /home/tuinshop/public_html/app/design/adminhtml/default/default/template/tax/notifications.phtml(58): Mage_Tax_Block_Adminhtml_Notifications->isDefaultStoreWithConflictingFptTaxConfigurationSettings()
#2 /home/tuinshop/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Template.php(241): include('/home/tuinshop/...')
#3 /home/tuinshop/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Template.php(272): Mage_Core_Block_Template->fetchView('adminhtml/defau...')
#4 /home/tuinshop/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Template.php(286): Mage_Core_Block_Template->renderView()
#5 /home/tuinshop/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/Block/Template.php(81): Mage_Core_Block_Template->_toHtml()
#6 /home/tuinshop/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Tax/Block/Adminhtml/Notifications.php(161): Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Template->_toHtml()
#7 /home/tuinshop/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Abstract.php(886): Mage_Tax_Block_Adminhtml_Notifications->_toHtml()
#8 /home/tuinshop/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Text/List.php(43): Mage_Core_Block_Abstract->toHtml()
#9 /home/tuinshop/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Abstract.php(886): Mage_Core_Block_Text_List->_toHtml()
#10 /home/tuinshop/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Abstract.php(605): Mage_Core_Block_Abstract->toHtml()
#11 /home/tuinshop/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Abstract.php(549): Mage_Core_Block_Abstract->_getChildHtml('notifications', true)
#12 /home/tuinshop/public_html/app/design/adminhtml/default/default/template/page.phtml(55): Mage_Core_Block_Abstract->getChildHtml('notifications')
#13 /home/tuinshop/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Template.php(241): include('/home/tuinshop/...')
#14 /home/tuinshop/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Template.php(272): Mage_Core_Block_Template->fetchView('adminhtml/defau...')
#15 /home/tuinshop/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Template.php(286): Mage_Core_Block_Template->renderView()
#16 /home/tuinshop/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/Block/Template.php(81): Mage_Core_Block_Template->_toHtml()
#17 /home/tuinshop/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Abstract.php(886): Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Template->_toHtml()
#18 /home/tuinshop/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Layout.php(555): Mage_Core_Block_Abstract->toHtml()
#19 /home/tuinshop/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Varien/Action.php(390): Mage_Core_Model_Layout->getOutput()
#20 /home/tuinshop/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/controllers/DashboardController.php(43): Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Action->renderLayout()
#21 /home/tuinshop/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Varien/Action.php(418): Mage_Adminhtml_DashboardController->indexAction()
#22 /home/tuinshop/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Varien/Router/Standard.php(250): Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Action->dispatch('index')
#23 /home/tuinshop/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Varien/Front.php(172): Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Router_Standard->match(Object(Mage_Core_Controller_Request_Http))
#24 /home/tuinshop/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/App.php(354): Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Front->dispatch()
#25 /home/tuinshop/public_html/app/Mage.php(683): Mage_Core_Model_App->run(Array)
#26 /home/tuinshop/public_html/index.php(87): Mage::run('', 'store')
#27 {main}
```

Comment: How did you perform you upgrade?

Answer (score 3):

It may be the admin files aren't updated correctly. I know this happend at least two persons already.

The solution is quite simple: Delete app/design/adminhtml/default and upload it again from a fresh Magento 1.9 installation.

Answer (score 0):

If you update your entire Magento application by downloading, un-taring and rsyncing Magento over your current version you should see the corrections.

WARNING: If you do have core changes they will be over written (You shouldn't have core changes)

Make sure you do this in a TEST environment and NOT production.

Command is as follows:

```
rsync -avz /path/to/new/magento/ /path/to/current/magento/html/
```